# Laravel 5.3 pdf rendering issue with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5.3

Call to undefined method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::setOrientation()

I am getting the above error on saving pdf.

```
 PDF::loadHTML($flight_plan_pdf_content)
   ->setPaper('a4')
   ->setOrientation('portrait')
   ->save($filePath . $fileName);
```

About mentioned is my code.

the same code is working with laravel 5.2 and "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` I can see that this is correct call

```
setPaper($paper, $orientation = 'portrait')
```

so for your example it should be

```
 PDF::loadHTML($flight_plan_pdf_content)
   ->setPaper('a4')
   ->save($filePath . $fileName);
```

no need for setting `portrait` since it's default value.

EDIT: This is related to the latest 0.7 version. If you are using any other just add `'portrait'` as the second parameter to the `setPaper` function

Comment: `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` version `0.5` had `setOrientation` so it's not Laravel related